# Relative URL not working in .less

Tags: css, fonts, less

I am using .less.
I defined a base .less that will be used in different locations.

```
http://<host>/<contextpath>/components/base.less
```

In this base file I want to define a font family. I am doing like this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?-b472hj');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix-b472hj') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff?-b472hj') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?-b472hj') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg?-b472hj#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

The fonts directory is in same directory as base.less.
Now I want to use this in two seperate location in different modules. 
When I use this font family it is not showing. If I change the url in and make it relative to one module then it will work in one module and not other. I am referencing this base in other .less file like this.

```
@import '../../components/base.less';
```

This import location will be relative to the module.
How can I resolve this ?
I want to reference fonts from current directory in which base.less is present. But right now it is relative to path at which base.less is imported.

For ex: module 1

```
/module1/style.less
module 2
/module2/somedirectory/somedirectory/style.less
```

If a import base.less in module2. The fonts directory path has to be specified relative to module2.
I don't want to change path depending on modules.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this.
By adding `~` before the url. It will be loaded relative to context path.

Like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src: ~"url('components/fonts/icomoon.eot?-b472hj')";
    src: ~"url('components/fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix-b472hj') format('embedded-opentype')",
         ~"url('components/fonts/icomoon.woff?-b472hj') format('woff')",
         ~"url('components/fonts/icomoon.ttf?-b472hj') format('truetype')",
         ~"url('components/fonts/icomoon.svg?-b472hj#icomoon') format('svg')";
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Your trick will work but it's more like not really recommended kludge. The proper method is to use [`--relative-urls` option](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-relative-urls). For more details see [#1238](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1238#issuecomment-40592080) and issues linked there.

Comment: not sure why `~` would work, but its usage (escaping) is described here http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-escaping

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue in my **webpack** config after digging for a *very* long time! Alter the following two options in `webpack.config.js` in order to satisfy the less compiler concerning relative URLs and generate the same relative URL in output:

1. Disable option `url` in the `css-loader` config.
2. Explicitly disable option `relativeUrls` in the `less-loader` config.

Hope this may help anybody someday :D

Greetings Christopher

```
{
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        url: false
    }
},
{
    loader: 'less-loader',
    options: {
        relativeUrls: false
    }
}
```